# In MVC5 how do I open a new window and pass a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5, html5-audio

I want to open an audio control in a new window and pass the filename to the audio control from an MVC5 View.

I am able to open a simple html page with the following code in the MVC5 view:

```
<a href="Music/Music.html"
   onclick="window.open('Music/Music.html',
                         'newwindow',
                         'width=600,height=200');
              return false;">html Link</a>
```

Then the Music.html page loads and plays the file using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="001.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> audio playback requires IE9 or above
  </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

That all works great, but I really want to pass the filename to the new page so the `src` is loaded with whatever filename I pass.  I do not how to do this, or if there is a better more efficient way to do this using other features of MVC5.

**Added after original post based on Joe Warner's proposed answer:**

This code is placed in index.vbhtml for the Home controller:

```
@Code
  Dim myUrl As String = "Music/Music.html?003.mp3"
End Code

<a href="@myUrl"
   onclick="window.open('@myUrl','_blank','width=600,height=100');
              return false;">
  html link a
</a>

<a href="@myUrl" onclick="myOpenWindow">
  html link b
</a>

@Section Scripts
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myOpenWindow() {
      window.open('@myUrl', '_blank', 'width=600,height=100').focus();
    }
  </script>
End Section
```

This is the target Music.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="" id="audio" type="audio/mp3"> audio playback requires IE9 or above
  </audio>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      document.getElementById('audio').src = window.location.search.substr(1)
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

For both `html link a` and `html link b` the target Music.html page loads and plays the 003.mp3.  But `html link a` opens a new window and `html link b` replaces the existing window.

I'm certain I'm making a basic mistake, but why can't I move the inline window.open javascript into a function so it can be called by other  elements that might exist on the page?

Comment: Could you assign the click handler in Javascript instead of the HTML (better to avoid inlined JS) and then generate the window URL to include a query including the filename?

Comment: That sounds good, but I'm still a novice at much of this.  I believe I get the click handler in Javascript and adding the query parameter, having done that previously; I just wasn't thinking about that while trying to get the basic process established.  I'm less clear on how the html page receives the file name sent by the Javascript and gets it to the audio control.

Comment: you can get the query param from the url and then set the src of the source element to the query param i think my answer lays it out if you have any questions let me know

Comment: @alan did my answer help at all?

Comment: @JoeWarner I apologize. I read your proposed answer within an hour of your post and I had this thought I should comment to let you know I was excited because your answer GREATLY helped in that I think I now see how this should work, but I was going to need a day or so to work through it.  Although I don't see too many comments like that, I should have listened to my thought & let you know. Yes, your post looks great. Give me a few days to confirm.  I always wait until I succeed with an answer before marking it as the answer in case there are other details that need to be added.

Comment: No worries let me know if you have any questions when you're back at it :) have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="Music/Music.html" onclick="openWindow">html Link</a>
```

attach a function to the on click then open the window with '_blank' this opens the document in a new window or tab.

```
function openWindow() {
  window.open("/Music/Music.html?filenameyouwant", "_blank",
    "width=600, height=200"
  ).focus();
}
```

Add an id to the source HTML

```
<source src="001.mp3" id="audio" type="audio/mp3">
```

Then select it using javascript and set the src of it to the end of the url you've gone to you'll want to wrap the getting of the url param till after the dom has loaded otherwise there will be no source element

> `?filenameyouwant`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.getElementById('audio').src = window.location.search.substr(1)
});
```

Comment: Your post helped me get close to the solution, but I'm still having some issues. 1st comment: the last script above doesn't run unless I use `function()` in place of `(event) =>`.  I assume that's a `<script>` VB vs C# issue & assuming so, there's no way you would have known I use VB.  But that script successfully pulls in the URL parameter which basically gets me there.  Thanks! But see my 2nd comment I'll post below in a moment.

Comment: 2nd comment: when the onclick function openWindow runs, it doesn't open a new window, it replaces my current tab. Even if I move my previous inline working script to the @Section Scripts region as a function, the exact javascript that opened a new window when used inline, fails to open a new window as a function. What might I be doing wrong? I posted above.

Comment: do you have _blank added as first param, yeah you should use function instead of () => if you're not using the latest version of javascript

Comment: I've changed the openWindow function if you'd like to try that

Comment: The only difference I saw in your update was that openWindow function added .focus().  I added that and it still overwrites the existing page.  I've got to be doing something simple wrong.  Did you see I added to my original post the current state of my testing code?  The target `.html` page is working fine per your URL param read suggestion.  My only problem is actually just getting rid of the inline javascript, which seems pretty dumb, but there you have it. Every javascript tutorial I read says this should be working.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: i added the url to the first param and removed adding it later you can take off focus it's not necessary.  Are you having trouble adding the function or a problem with how its running i'll try help you out if i can :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167363/discussion-between-alan-and-joe-warner).